# Adding numbers from multiple columns and different rows in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following data.

[image]

And I am hoping to add values C and D from 2000, with A from 2001, and create a new column in the data frame, which should look like something like this

[image]

where the last column in 2003 is blank because it is incomplete (no data in A, 2004)

I've tried:

```
sum_cda = df.columns[2:4].... 

df['sum'] = df[sum_cda].sum(axis=1)
```

I am a newbie in both python and pandas, and I've tried searching the internet for answers to no avail.

Thank you!

---

FOLLOW UP QUESTION:

what if I want to get the minimum or count or max values between CDA? df['sum'] = df[['C', 'D']].min(axis=1)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sum` for columns `C, D` and then add shifted column `A` by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['sum'] = df[['C', 'D']].sum(axis=1).add(df['A'].shift(-1))
```

If need also add missing years like `2002` use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = df.reindex(range(df.index.min(), df.index.max() + 1))
df['sum'] = df[['C', 'D']].sum(axis=1).add(df['A'].shift(-1))
```

EDIT:

> I want to get the minimum or count or max of CDA?

Then first assign new column:

```
df['sum'] = df.assign(shifted = df['A'].shift(-1))[['shifted', 'C', 'D']].sum(axis=1)
df['max'] = df.assign(shifted = df['A'].shift(-1))[['shifted', 'C', 'D']].max(axis=1)
df['min'] = df.assign(shifted = df['A'].shift(-1))[['shifted', 'C', 'D']].min(axis=1)
```

But last value is also count, if need `NaN` set it manually:

```
df.loc[df.index[-1], 'sum'] = np.nan
df.loc[df.index[-1], 'max'] = np.nan
df.loc[df.index[-1], 'min'] = np.nan
```

Comment: neat! Thank you.

but what if I want to get the minimum or count or max values between CDA?


df['sum'] = df[['C', 'D']].min(axis=1)...